# iPhone Bedtime Options for Different Days

Tags: iphone, settings, alarm

I use the Bedtime settings on the iPhone but I'd like to have different settings for different days. For instance, I have the same alarm time for Monday-Friday but would like a later alarm time for the weekend. I don't see where option is available.

[image: Bedtime Options screenshot]